# Searching items causes lags

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have following problem. Let's say I have DOM like this.

```
<div class="results">
  <div class="result">
    <div class="title">Aaa</div>
  </div>
  <div class="result filtered-out">
    <div class="title">Aab</div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <div class="title">Aac</div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <div class="title">Aad</div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <div class="title">Aae</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and an input field like this

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

And now I try to filter the results with a simple function defined by this

```
var searchBox = $(this);
searchBox.keyup(function(){
  var searchBox = $(this);
  var items = $(".results .result:not(.filtered-out)");
  items.each(function(){
    var title  = $(this).find(".title").html();
    if(title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBox.val().toLowerCase())!== -1)
      $(this).show();
    else
      $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

So the problem is that the list of results is quite long something between 100 and 200 elements and whenever I type something into the search input the code executes very long. Maybe around 2-3 seconds. Is there any other approach to solve this "lag"? Thank you for any advices!

**EDIT** Maybe something like delayed script execution or asynchronous script execution (like in ajax)?

Comment: Don't use the DOM as a datastore, it's not meant to be one. Keep your data separate and work on that.

Comment: That's an idea. I'm going for it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to use the DOM as a datasource, it's not meant for it and is therefore slow. Personally I would recommend using a small MVVM library or something similar so you don't have to manually manage the DOM yourself.
I've used [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) below, but you could just as well use any similar solution. Keeping your data in the code will allow you to operate on it a lot faster since you don't have to re-request it all the time and you avoid doing a lot of work for modifications. All operations below are done on 1000 objects:

```js
var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  items.push({
    title: 'Item #' + i
  });
}
var v = new Vue({
  el: '#list',
  data: {
    items: items,
    input: ""
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {
      var value = ("" || this.input).trim().toLowerCase();
      if (!value.length) return this.items;
      return this.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <input placeholder="Search" v-model="input" />
  <ol>
    <li v-repeat="filteredItems">{{title}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right indeed. I combined all of the help from answers above and yours. First of all, I am searching through an array, rather than DOM (as you said) now the search is pretty much seamless, BUT!!! The one thing that still does lag is not the searching itself but the showing and hiding the elements. There I didn't use Vue but vanilla getelementbyid and the process is now as fast as I desired :)

Answer (score 1):

When searching the dom through many elements it is recommended to use javascript as opposed to jQuery if speed is what you are after. jQuery has it's purpose but for large amounts of dom searching using javascripts getElementById or querySelector / querySelectorAll is going to be much much faster. If you check this jsPerf [example](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/44) you can see that the jQuery selector operates roughly 94% slower than the comparable getElementById.

Comment: My selectors were 100% slower than vanilla js :D :D Thanks for the link!!

Comment: No problem! As a personal rule of thumb (and this is my own preference) I do all DOM searching with javascript. Much faster that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using some logging to figure out which part is taking the longest.  If you find that it's the `items` selector (with the psuedo-not), you could try to optimize that, however I don't see anything about the `filtered-out` class so I'm not sure exactly what that does.

Here's some simple optimizations though:

```
var searchBox = $(this);
searchBox.keyup(function(){
  var $searchBox = $(this);
  var searchBoxVal = $searchBox.val().toLowerCase();
  var items = $(".results .result:not(.filtered-out)");
  items.each(function(){
    var $item = $(this);
    var title  = $item.find(".title").html();
    if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBoxVal) !== -1)
      $item.show();
    else
      $item.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: That filtered out thing means the element is hidden therefore no need for search. I've applied the changes and yet the thing is already faster. I'll try the answer from asmithdev and if that's not fast enough I'll do it as @Nit commented (seems to be the most reasonable solution) nevertheless, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess the lag is because you are performing the search based on the DOM elements, and at the same time manipulating them with hiding/ showing.

I suppose the DOM is populated from some data source? If so it'll be better to perform the search/ filter from that data source, then use the filtered data set to populate the DOM again. (And even if you don't have the data source at first, you can build one by reading the original DOM)

Comment: Indeed you are correct. Therefore I am already applying some changes as you proposed because @Nit already advised me to do so.